# Get Cell and settitle 'Cell'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I get 'Cell A2' and I want make settitle 'A2 '
How to do? please help me

```
function MyFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    var value1 = sheet.getRange('A2').getValue();

    var form = FormApp.openByUrl("my form url");
    var item25 = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
    item25.setTitle('A2')
    item25.setChoices([
        item25.createChoice('B2'),
        item25.createChoice('B2')
    ])
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Your code already sets the title to the string literal "A2". Did you mean you want to set the title of the newly added item to be the **value** of the spreadsheet cell A2?

Comment: yes, I want to add value of the spreadsheeet cell A2

Answer (score 1):

Do `item25.setTitle(value1)` instead of `item25.setTitle('A2')`.

Otherwise you are not using the variable `value1`.

If you take a look at the documentation, [getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) returns an object (I suppose an string in this case) and [setTitle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#settitletitle) requires an string, so you can use value1 in setTitle.

I recommend you to take a look at some javascript documentation, like [variables](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp) and [data type](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp).